# sql select query excluding certain values

Tags: sql, oracle

The requirement is to exclude ItemA and ItemE from the search as they contain value 1 in columnB.

[image]

The final result should be something like this

[image]

I have tried `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ColumnB not like '1'` , but this just removes the rows having 1 , I want the whole ITEM A/ITEM E removed as the contain value 1.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: ItemC contains a 3, so your expected results make no sense.

Comment: You mean item A and item E right ?

Comment: Apologies I meant item A and item E

Comment: Then please edit your question such that it is correct.

Comment: your question is very unclear, and not match title with body!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablee
WHERE ColumnA NOT IN (
  SELECT columnA FROM tablee
  WHERE columnB = 1
);
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM tablee t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM tablee t2
  WHERE t2.columnB = 1 and t1.columnA = t2.columnA
);
```

Comment: I did the same thing before you posted this(see my sqlfiddle below). But I am going to accept this as the solution as this the best and simplest approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

First we make a sub-query that looks for rows with ColumnB = '1'. Then we left join that sub query to our main table on matching ColumnA names. Items that have a different row with a '1' in ColumnB will now have a value there, other rows will just have NULL because of the left join. We then use a where to only find the ones that didn't have a match.

```
SELECT main.* from my_table AS main
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM my_table 
    WHERE ColumnB = '1' 
    ) AS remove
ON remove.ColumnA = main.ColumnA
WHERE remove.ColumnB != '1'
```

To learn more about sql go through the primer at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: Mate aplogies had already tried this before , I have already edited the question and added that . This doesn't fect the result I am looking for as it removes only rows containing 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys . I came up with the solution

```
select * 
from test 
where columnA not in  (select columnA from test where ColumnB = 1 )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0f07/2

Comment: Note that this will not work properly if `ColumnA` contains `NULL` VALUES

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from my_table where ColumnA!=ItemA and ColumnA!=ItemE;
```